# Customized popup window leads to leaked window.

Tags: android, android-dialog

I have the following code for displaying a customized popup, however executing the same leads to a leaked window error, I am not able to determine how to resolve it. Following is my code:

```
    public void Reminder() {
    dDialog = new Dialog(Farrier.this);
    dDialog.setContentView(R.layout.farrierpop2);
    dDialog.setTitle("Reminder");
    dDialog.setCancelable(true);
    final Button pop1 = (Button) dDialog.findViewById(R.id.Btn1);
    pop1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
            intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
            intent.putExtra("title", IDB);
            intent.putExtra("description", "Farrier Service");
            intent.putExtra("beginTime", "eventStartInMillis");
            intent.putExtra("endTime", "eventEndInMillis");
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
    Button pop2 = (Button) dDialog.findViewById(R.id.Btn2);
    pop2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // dDialog.dismiss();
            Intent ourpartner = new Intent(Farrier.this, FarrierSch.class);
            startActivity(ourpartner);
            finish();
        }
    });
    dDialog.show();
}
```

The Stack Trace is:

```
*07-01 11:30:18.646: E/WindowManager(407): Activity com.gallops.Farrier has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@45fe7468 that was originally added here
07-01 11:30:18.646: E/WindowManager(407): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.gallops.Farrier has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@45fe7468 that was originally added here
07-01 11:30:18.646: E/WindowManager(407):   at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:227)
07-01 11:30:18.646: E/WindowManager(407):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
07-01 11:30:18.646: E/WindowManager(407):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
07-01 11:30:18.646: E/WindowManager(407):   at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
07-01 11:30:18.646: E/WindowManager(407):   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:239)
07-01 11:30:18.646: E/WindowManager(407):   at com.gallops.Farrier.Reminder(Farrier.java:185)
07-01 11:30:18.646: E/WindowManager(407):   at com.gallops.Farrier$2.onClick(Farrier.java:915)
07-01 11:30:18.646: E/WindowManager(407):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
07-01 11:30:18.646: E/WindowManager(407):   at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179)
07-01 11:30:18.646: E/WindowManager(407):   at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6541)
07-01 11:30:18.646: E/WindowManager(407):   at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
07-01 11:30:18.646: E/WindowManager(407):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
07-01 11:30:18.646: E/WindowManager(407):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
07-01 11:30:18.646: E/WindowManager(407):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
07-01 11:30:18.646: E/WindowManager(407):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
07-01 11:30:18.646: E/WindowManager(407):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
07-01 11:30:18.646: E/WindowManager(407):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
07-01 11:30:18.646: E/WindowManager(407):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
07-01 11:30:18.646: E/WindowManager(407):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
07-01 11:30:18.646: E/WindowManager(407):   at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)
07-01 11:30:18.646: E/WindowManager(407):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
07-01 11:30:18.646: E/WindowManager(407):   at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1691)
07-01 11:30:18.646: E/WindowManager(407):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-01 11:30:18.646: E/WindowManager(407):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-01 11:30:18.646: E/WindowManager(407):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
07-01 11:30:18.646: E/WindowManager(407):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-01 11:30:18.646: E/WindowManager(407):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-01 11:30:18.646: E/WindowManager(407):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
07-01 11:30:18.646: E/WindowManager(407):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
07-01 11:30:18.646: E/WindowManager(407):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)*
```

Comment: dismiss the dialog before finishing activity.

Comment: Works like a charm, type this in the Answer box and I'll accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are finishing the parent activity of your dialog
you have to dismiss dialog first and
you have to set onCancleListener to your dialog and in onCancleListener start other activity and finish this activity

```
dDialog.setOnCancleListener();

@Override
onCancle()
{
startactivityone();

OR

startactivitytwo();
}

public void Reminder() {
dDialog = new Dialog(Farrier.this);
dDialog.setContentView(R.layout.farrierpop2);
dDialog.setTitle("Reminder");
dDialog.setCancelable(true);
final Button pop1 = (Button) dDialog.findViewById(R.id.Btn1);
pop1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
        intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
        intent.putExtra("title", IDB);
        intent.putExtra("description", "Farrier Service");
        intent.putExtra("beginTime", "eventStartInMillis");
        intent.putExtra("endTime", "eventEndInMillis");
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
});
Button pop2 = (Button) dDialog.findViewById(R.id.Btn2);
pop2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // dDialog.dismiss();
        Intent ourpartner = new Intent(Farrier.this, FarrierSch.class);
        startActivity(ourpartner);
        finish();
    }
});
dDialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to `dismiss` your `dialog` while `existing` your current `activity`,

```
 if(dDialog.isShowing()){
   dDialog.dismiss();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use dialog fragments. Dialogs are deprecated. (Possibly due to those kind of problems).

Comment: See this post, it explains how to use dialogs inside fragments. http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i was calling finish() from with in the popup. It was a videoplayer, which shows a title bar with a close button on top. The activity closes once clicked close button in the popup.

This obviously led to leaks, because the popup is still showing when finish() is called. Sorted this out by checking if the popup is visible in the parentActivity and closed it

```
@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mVideoView != null) {
            mVideoView = null;

        }
        if(mMediaController.isShowing()){
            mMediaController.hide();
            mMediaController=null;          
        }
    }
```